# Domain name shows error runs fine with index.php

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I'm getting this error

```
Warning: include(/var/chroot/home/content/phplib/functions.library.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/72/10433372/html/index.php on line 9

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/var/chroot/home/content/phplib/functions.library.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/72/10433372/html/index.php on line 9
```

The problem is it is not opening the website when I type www.domain.com but works fine when I type www.domain.com/index.php 
The website was running fine till now.
I also tried redirecting to index.php in htaccess file but still errors not going away. Also I supplied absolute path but still the same error. Does anyone know any other solution for this.

htaccess file contents:-

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</Files>

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|inc)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>





#php_flag magic_quotes_gpc on 
#php_flag register_globals on




### Rewrite Rules ######################################### 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule services/(.*)/(.*)      services/detail.php?i_servicesID=$1
RewriteRule study-abroad/(.*)/(.*)  study-abroad/detail.php?url=$1&about=$2
```

Comment: what are the permissions on the htaccess file?

Comment: Look at `/var/chroot/home/content/phplib/functions.library.php`. The file doesn't exist in that path. But is that the path you were expecting it to be loading from? What path *were* you expecting? What's the difference between the two? Maybe there's a clue in that.